# TypeError: index_queryset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack, pysolr

```
Django==3.2.5
django-haystack==3.0
pysolr==3.9.0

Solr = 8.9.0
```

I am following the tutorial as in
https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html to create an Django application with Solr.

While executing `./manage.py rebuild_index`, I am getting an error like:

```
 **File "/..../tele_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", 
line  202, in build_queryset
index_qs = self.index_queryset(using=using)
TypeError: index_queryset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'**
```

I am stuck up since 3 days solving this error. Tried to downgrade each of
the packages (Django, pysolr, haystack with solr 6.6, but didn't help me.

Please help me to get out of this circle of upgrading and downgrading...
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is `self.index_queryset` implemented? Does it take a `using` parameter?

Comment: Yes...It takes using as a parameter. I have checked

Comment: Show the code where you inherit from `SearchIndex` or a similar class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you time... My issue got resolved. There was a problem in my function definition ( index_queryset). I missed to give the parameter using.

Answer (score 1):

So I've just read the sources from `django-haystack` 3.0 and there are several weird things.

First thing is that the `using` parameter is never used in the function definition (maybe its for subclasses, I didnt dig that far):

```
def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """
        Get the default QuerySet to index when doing a full update.
        Subclasses can override this method to avoid indexing certain objects.
        """
        return self.get_model()._default_manager.all()
```

Back to your error, in the `build_queryset` method, the parameter `using` is passed to the function index_queryset not the queryset itself, so I can't see why it would raise an error.

Last thing is, I tested with both Django 2 and 3 projets, and using is always a method of queryset, not an argument, so I'm quite confused. Is your traceback from `Django 3.2` and `haystack 3.0` ?

Comment: Yes.... This traceback is from Django 3.2 and haystack 3. Even I too couldn't see the usage of 'using'. But being novice to solr, I am afraid of deleting the argument from the function already given by package.

Comment: Might be worth to open an issue in Github or have a look to existing ones.

Comment: My issue got resolved..There was the issue in the class I created for Index. Thanks a lot for your time.   Previously I missed to write the second parameter (using).                                                                    def index_queryset(self,using=None):  
       return self.get_model().objects.all()